# ld: cannot find -ljson

Tags: gcc, dynamic-linking

I tried running

```
sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-dev
```

with no luck. Was not able to find anything useful by googling either. Anyone know what package I need to install to be able to link json?

Comment: There are several json libs in the repos, perhaps you meant libjson0-dev which does appear to have -ljson

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  jJust press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install libjson0 libjson0-dev
```